# jquery find image title attribute and toggle class of according list item

Tags: jquery

I have a list of images with title attributes and a separate list of names.

On mouse hover on the images i want to toggle css class on a list item on the name list.

Therefor i have to take the value of the current title tag and have to search for the according text in the names list.

```
       <ul class="staff-photos">
          <li class="standard">
            <%= image_tag("footer/edith_hansmann.jpg", alt: "Edith Hansmann", title: "Edith Hansmann") %>
          </li>
          <li class="standard">
            <%= image_tag("footer/christine_jean.jpg", alt: "Christine Jean", title: "Christine Jean") %>
          </li>
       </ul>

      <ul class="staff-names">
        <li><span class="hover-name">EDITH HANSMANN</span>  | Head of Design</li>
        <li><span class="hover-name">CHRISTINE JEAN</span>  | Head of Marketing</li>
```

My javascript:

```
  // mouse hover on staff page image toggles CSS class of staff name list item
  $('ul.staff-photos img').hover(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('title');
    $('.hover-name').text().match(name).toggleClass('active');
  });
```

I have trouble with comparing the according list item:

```
$('.hover-name').text()
"EDITH HANSMANNCHRISTINE JEAN"
```

How can i achieve that the according list item get toggled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your logic around the `match`, as you get the text of all the `span` elements in a single string instead of comparing them individually.

You can achieve what you require by using the `filter()` method to find the `span` elements with `text()` that matches the hovered `img` elements' `title` attribute. Try this:

```
$('ul.staff-photos img').hover(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('title').toLowerCase();
    $('.hover-name').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().toLowerCase() == name;
    }).toggleClass('active');
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/d5hao1ou/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector:

```
var name = $(this).attr('title').toUpperCase();
$('.hover-name:contains("'+ name +'")').toggleClass('active');
```

- 1st part will turn the name from any case to upper case, so that we can match exactly with all upper case text inside `.hover-name`
- 2nd part will select all the elements containing that word and `toggle` the class active based on the elements found.